# Kibana - PollError ActionRequestValidationException

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

New to Elasticsearch and Kibana, ive one to the website and downloaded both,
elasticsearch 6.7.0 and kibana 6.7.0

Followed the instructions, elasticsearch starts up, the console output is a bit messy but i can get to the default localhost:9200/ and it shows the json data fine.

In Kibana i edited the kibana.yml file in config and uncommented the default line `elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://localhost:9200"]`

Then ran bin/kibana

it seems to start up but then am flooded with a info message of
`[info][task_manager] Installing .kibana_task_manager index template version: 6070099`
and a warning of
`[task_manager] PollError ActionRequestValidationException[Validation Failed: 1: template is missing;]`

There were no other instructions besides those to start it up, did i miss something?, looks like a template is missing?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you solve it?